# Calculation of distribution of a gaussian process

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution

currently finishing the last year of PhD in statistics, we wonder if you could help us with the following.

Let $T = [0,1]$ and $X = \left( X_{t}, t \in T \right)$ be a gaussian process with mean function $m$ and covariance function $W$. Parentheses in functions are omitted in this notation. We write $X \sim GP(m,W)$.

In a first time, suppose that the sample paths $t \mapsto X_{t}$ are continuous a.s. and let $Y$ be the stochastic process defined on $T$ by :
$$Y_{t} = \int_{0}^{t} X(u) du,\mbox{ a.s.}.$$

The question is : what can you say about the law of $Y$ ? In particular, do you believe it to be $GP(m^{\star},W^{\star})$, given by :
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
m^{\star}(t) & = & \int_{0}^{t} m(u)du,\\
W^{\star}(s,t) & = & \int_{0}^{s} \int_{0}^{t} W(u,v)dudv.
\end{array}$$

If the preceding statement is true, could you please give us some references?

In a second time, suppose that the sample paths $t \mapsto X_{t}$ are differentiable a.s. and let $Z$ be the stochastic process defined on $T$ by :
$$Z_{t} = \frac{dX_{t}}{dt},\mbox{ a.s.}.$$

The question is now : what can you say about the law of $Z$? Do you have any reference where we could find a result?

We would be very grateful for any feedback you can give us. Thank you very much.